# IIS7, web.config to allow only static file handler in directory /uploads of website

Tags: security, iis-7, web-config, httphandler

If it's possible which I think so, How do I modify my web.config to make a sub directory static -- files inside will only processed as static file, even if its name is "aspx" or something else?
Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you block `.as?x` uploads?

Comment: because there could be a lot more than .as?x, such as .php, .asp, and so on.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Add the following to a `web.config` file in the folder containing the files you wish to be served only as static content:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
           <clear />
            <add 
                name="StaticFile" 
                path="*" verb="*" 
                modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule" 
                resourceType="Either" 
                requireAccess="Read" />
        </handlers>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".*" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Tested ok on IIS and IIS Express, though it does not work on VS integrated Web Server.

Comment: @deerchao - no it won't because the integrated "cassini" server doesn't support `<system.webServer>`.

Comment: That works until someone uploads a new web.config into your open uploads folder and redefines all handlers. See my [answer here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/123099/86063) . See [this link](http://spidersec.ninja/rce-on-iis-webserver-via-web-config/) for exploit example.

Comment: @drizin - Sure....but not everyone has access to the root web.config. If someone not trusted by your org is able to upload random stuff to your site then it's pretty much game over anyway.

Comment: I received a 403.3 because of insufficient permissions. Within the `<handlers>` tag, I added `<remove name="StaticFile" />` instead of `<clear />` and changed the `requireAccess` property value from `Write`  to `Read`.

Comment: @WouterVanherck glad you found my answer helpful :)