# Publish To Static Address Site on IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

I designed a web application using `asp.net` . Now I want to publish this site on `IIS` server using a static IP address.

***The steps that I did as follows:***

1. under IIS sites folder I created a new site.
2. I selected the website name, application pool, physical path of the web app folder, the protocol `(HTTP)`, public `IP` address  and the port(80). Then , I tried to browse and I got this error :

> The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

What is the problem, or which steps have I missed?

Comment: You probably have a problem in you Web.Config file (see this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942055)

Comment: ye, remember also to switch custom error mode off

Comment: Thanks Kevin ..Thanks Eon Rusted

Comment: Eon Rusted could you please tell me how to switch custom error off??

Comment: Now I got this type of error : **The requested content appears to be script and will not be served by the static file handler**

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762287/script-not-served-by-static-file-handler-on-iis7-5

Comment: Thank you Kevin ..Actually I checked this page before and I still have this error.

Answer (score 0):

Either the pool .netframework version is not correct (maybe it needs v4.0 while your pool is only v2.0) or the mode is not correct (classic or integrated). One addional factor is Sharing the publish folder, (right click the folder with windows explorer > Properties > Sharing > Make it shared for "everyone" read & write.