# How to install umbraco in root folder of the IIS server in localhost?

Tags: umbraco

I have try to install Umbraco in root path (C:\inetpub\wwwroot) of the IIS. I have just download the umbraco and zip into the root folder. And add the website from IIS Manager. I have selected the dot net framework version as 4.0 and Managed Pipeline mode as Classic from Application Pool.

While I have browse the application , it seems an error.

### HTTP Error 404.17 - Not Found

**The requested content appears to be script and will not be served by the static file handler.**

**Module    StaticFileModule

Notification    ExecuteRequestHandler

Handler StaticFile

Error Code  0x80070032

Physical Path   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\umbraco\default.aspx

Logon Method    Anonymous

Logon User  Anonymous**

How to solve this

Comment: Did you convert the Umbraco folder to an application in IIS?

Comment: You meant to adding website in IIS. right? I have added.

Comment: You can try some of the solutions mentioned in this SO question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762287/script-not-served-by-static-file-handler-on-iis7-5

Answer (score 1):

You don't have all necessary roles installed in your IIS

[image]

Comment: I give the configuration as mentioned above. But its not working.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help, but it's my understanding Umbraco needs to be run in Integrated mode.

What version did you install?

Comment: I have using Umbraco 6 for the development. I can also use both modes. But its not working