# Use cs file as Web handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7.5

I want my `ascx.cs` file to work as `ashx` file for some reason. I have implemented `System.Web.IHttpHandler` into it and registered it as a handler in web.config

```
<httpHandlers>
.
.
.
<add path="*.cs" verb="*" type="Namespace.ClassName, Assembly.dll" validate="false" />
</httpHandlers>
```

And added following code in request filtering under `System.WebServer` in `web.config'

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <fileExtensions allowUnlisted="true">
      <remove fileExtension=".cs" />
      <add fileExtension=".cs" allowed="true" />
    </fileExtensions>
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

but when I open `.cs` file from browser, it gives me error.

> HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found
>
> The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.

with following details

> Module StaticFileModule
>
> Notification   ExecuteRequestHandler
>
> Handler    StaticFile
>
> Error Code 0x80070032
>
> Requested URL  http://localhost:80/MyClass.ascx.cs
>
> Physical Path  MyPath
>
> Logon Method   Anonymous
>
> Logon User Anonymous

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a separate section for static files, see here [IIS7, web.config to allow only static file handler in directory /uploads of website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061678/iis7-web-config-to-allow-only-static-file-handler-in-directory-uploads-of-webs)
Its different to exactly what you want, but the static file concept is shown.

Comment: sorry, but it has nothing to do with my question.

Comment: @anonymous You're quite right, i realised after i had posted this was the wrong thing. Should i delete it? Dont want to muddy the water of the responses to your question