# Azure and Django error: "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable"

Tags: django, azure

I believe the error I am getting is due to how Django is trying to serve the static files. The default azure landing page works but as soon as I go to /admin/ I get the error message:

> "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name
>   changed, or is temporarily unavailable"

This here is the static files infomation from the Settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    #'/var/www/static/',
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static_cdn') //used in development
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'media_cdn')//used in development
```

and in D:\home\site\wwwroot\static I have got the following web.config from this answer here:

[IIS7, web.config to allow only static file handler in directory /uploads of website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061678/iis7-web-config-to-allow-only-static-file-handler-in-directory-uploads-of-webs/2066040#2066040)

**Edit:**

```
<configuration>

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="PythonHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
      <add name="PythonHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule"
           scriptProcessor="D:\home\python364x64\Scripts\pip3.exe"
           resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script"/>
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform processPath="D:\home\python364x64\python.exe"
                  arguments="D:\home\site\wwwroot\runserver.py --port %HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%"
                  stdoutLogEnabled="true"
                  stdoutLogFile="D:\home\LogFiles\python.log"
                  startupTimeLimit="60"
                  processesPerApplication="16">
      <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="SERVER_PORT" value="%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%" />
      </environmentVariables>
    </httpPlatform>
  <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed"></httpErrors>

  </system.webServer>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="django.core.wsgi.get_wsgi_application()"/>
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\home\python364x64\Scripts"/>
    <add key="WSGI_LOG" value="D:\home\LogFiles\wfastcgi.log"/>
    <add key="DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" value="FTAData.settings" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Why would you think this has anything to do with static? If you only see the Azure landing page, then your Django project is not configured to be served at all. Where is the actual Azure config for the Django site?

Comment: I assumed that as there is no index page in my project (it has been unnecessary up until now). I updated my question and added the Web.config file if that is the file you meant?