# Flask static folder not served on IIS

Tags: flask, iis, static

I serve an application under a website on IIS but I can't access static folder (where are my CSS files and pictures).
I tried few options following tips ([IIS7, web.config to allow only static file handler in directory /uploads of website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061678/iis7-web-config-to-allow-only-static-file-handler-in-directory-uploads-of-webs) and [How to fetch static CSS files with django on IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32312590/how-to-fetch-static-css-files-with-django-on-iis)) but neither works.

My structure on IIS is below with static as a virtual directory of the app:
[image: IIS structure]

My app is online but without CSS and pictures.

What is the solution?
Thanks for your help!

**Edit on 1st of February:**

[image: Handler on static folder]

[image: web.config file]

Comment: You can try to remove the Flask handler in virtual directory handler mapping.

Comment: I have only one handler which is StaticFileModule. I've made an edit on the original post with web.config code snippet + handler on static folder. Thank you for your time for helping.

Comment: How did you publish the Flask project to IIS? Is it through VS?

Comment: I put the folder on the server, created a website on IIS manager, then an app with an alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think static folder does not need to use virtual directory.

Here is my demo:

I created a Flask project using the default template in VS and published it to the folder:

[image]

web.config is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="Flask" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Python\python.exe|C:\Python\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
                <security> 
            <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true"></requestFiltering> 
        </security> 
    </system.webServer>
       <appSettings>
        <!-- Required settings -->
        <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="FlaskWebProject1.app" />
        <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="~/" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

The directory structure of this project in IIS is as follows:

[image]

[image]

**UDDATE:**

[image]

***It should be noted that when adding static files as virtual directories, they must be added under the main application.***

[image]

[image]

The static folder needs to be at the same level as flask.Because the request for static files by default is requested under the main application:

[image]

Comment: It is very clear, thank you. But I have no issue when I serve the app as a website, but not as an application with an alias. Could you try your demo as application under website please?

Comment: Woooow, this is huge, thanks a lot for your help!!! It works and it is very clear! But how can I store multiple apps under a same website with different static folders? Really and siuncerely many thanks, it was a nightmare!