# IIS how to view a file stored on the Physical Path on a locally hosted webpage

Tags: iis

I have been attempting to access some files I have in a local directory via a locally hosted web site using IIS (Internet Information Services Manager).
The current file types in the folder are CSS, CSV and HTML.

I cannot seem to find any data on these sites, however, I believe something is there as when I change the web URL slightly it states "page can’t be found" rather than showing a blank page.

I have been looking through IIS extensively for a way to make these files ether download/become visible/show file contents/display the HTML

I have the file system set up as both the main website and as another file, under the Default website (as seen below) however, I cannot get either of these two methods to show me the files or anything for that matter.

[image: IIS lay out]

Comment: Right click on the site in IIS Manager and select Explore.

Comment: That brings me to a blank page with no data on it

Comment: It should be noted that when adding static files as virtual directories, they must be added under the main application. The request for static files by default is requested under the main application. There is a similar question in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65959265/flask-static-folder-not-served-on-iis/66022090#66022090